# TableView - Tab Navigation - Connection Inspector Issue

Tags: uitableview, connection

Hey, I'm very new and im pretty confused.

I have 3 tabs, using my tab navigation template.

News Tab - > RssFunController(view)
MAP      - > SecondView
Podcast   -> ThirdView

Ok my question is , I want to display a simply table with items in SecondView, I have created a NSMutableArray *listOfItems;  in file RootViewController.h

And in RootViewController.m I have sent up my view table details etc.

My problem is how do I set up my SecondView.xib tree to show my table with the items?

Im confused how i connect my data source and various things.

THANKS! :) , I hope you can help me.

Comment: I have found a similar question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2261263/uitableview-uinavigationcontroller-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-xxx

But they dont explain the connections I need to do in detail.

I tired connecting my table view (source) to my File owner which is set to RootViewController class.

Does not work. 

This is soooooo annoying :) , oh how I miss Java :)